# Generate checkout link to customers

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have created orders programmatically with money payment method with a custom status, then I need to generate a link to send customers to the checkout to update the method payment and complete the order.

Is it possible do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already created the order. In Magento flow, this means, that the system is already transferred data from quote to order. You can create functionality to update this order, but you would have to create own custom controller for this. Another way is to fill new quote with information from order and sent to customer usual checkout link. After new order will be created by the user with necessary payment info just cancel old order using observer.